# CKEditor throws error after adding Notification Plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I am attempting to add the notification plugin to CKEditor and I receive the following error when I go on any page implementing the CKEditor regardless if it attempts to use the Notification Plugin or not

```
Uncaught TypeError: CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer is not a function
   at Area (plugin.js?t=D2LI:448)
   at Object.init (plugin.js?t=D2LI:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:221)
   at n (ckeditor.js:202)
   at Array.m (ckeditor.js:202)
   at o (ckeditor.js:202)
   at ckeditor.js:203
```

I am clearly including the plugin since I am getting these errors.

this is the line of code in the plugin that is causing the error.

```
this._uiBuffer = CKEDITOR.tools.eventsBuffer( 10, this._layout, this );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.tools-method-eventsBuffer.

The error means that `tools` object doesn't have `eventsBuffer` method. There are two explanations which come to my mind:

1. This method is available since CKEditor 4.2.1. Please check your `ckeditor/CHANGES.md` file (**your version is at the top**) to find out which editor version you use. If your editor is anything below 4.2.1, please upgrade it to latest version. Please also note that if you want to use notifications you need to use at least CKEditor 4.5 - https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.notification so upgrading to 4.2.1 won't help in this case.
2. This is a long shot but another possibility is that you have a third-party script which conflicts with CKEditor thus you get such result. If your editor is up to date, please try disabling other scripts, clearing browser's cache according to this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache) and checking the result one more time.

**NOTE:** To find out your version you can also click question mark icon on the toolbar (it is available if you have [About](https://ckeditor.com/addon/about) plugin installed).